# converting video to image through ffmpeg in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ffmpeg

I am using FrameExtractor in iphone.

In the simulator, it works fine.

When I run on a real device, it gives the following error:

```
"-[VideoFrameExtractor setupScaler] in VideoFrameExtractor.o"
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone/comment-page-1#comment-1116).  The tutorial suggests that I should use the following line, but *where I should I place this line?*

```
 ./configure --enable-cross-compile --arch=c --target-os=darwin --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk --cpu=arm6 --extra-cflags='-arch armv6' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6'
```

Answer (score 0):

That line is for compiling FFMPEG. Please take a look at this [project](https://github.com/gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build). There you will see scripts for compiling ffmpeg for iphone.